# An opportunist friend

Tags: riddle

I could be there, yet I'll stay hidden.
Hidden I'll stay, but you'll need me.
Need me you will, so I may appear.
Appear I may, I don't decide.
Decide I don't, my master does.

I'm a word, I tell you words.
I've a task, you know my task.
I'm short, I shorten your path.
I've the answer, now tell me it!

**What am I?**

**Hint #1:**

> I'm not far.

**Hint #2:**

> Far I'm not, indeed I'm here.

Comment: I really hope the answer isn't 'boner'......

Comment: Nah it is not...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Are you

> a hint?

I could be there, yet I'll stay hidden.

> Hints are often hidden by spoiler tags

Hidden I'll stay, but you'll need me.
Need me you will, so I may appear.

> As people fail to guess the correct answers, hints are given.

Appear I may, I don't decide.
Decide I don't, my master does.

> The creator of the riddle chooses when to give hints.

I'm a word, I tell you words.

> "hint" is a word, and a hint provides many helpful words.

I've a task, you know my task.

> The task is helping people figure out the riddle.

I'm short, I shorten your path.

> Hints are usually shorter than the original clue/riddle, and they help you get to the solution.

I've the answer, now tell me it!

> Hints, by their nature, allude to the correct answer, as if they are beckoning for you to get it right.

Comment: That's it! Well done!

Answer (score 5):

It must be the

> apostrophe-sign, like in "I'm" or  "I've"

Explanation:

> First of all, the apostrophe is used throughout the whole riddle, so it is probably the clue.

I could be there, yet I'll stay hidden.
Hidden I'll stay, but you'll need me.
Need me you will, so I may appear.
Appear I may, I don't decide.
Decide I don't, my master does.

> The apostrophe may appear or may not. The writer decides if to include the apostrophe.

I'm a word, I tell you words.
I've a task, you know my task.
I'm short, I shorten your path.
I've the answer, now tell me it!

> The apostrophe makes the statement shorter. It is no word, but it "tells" you words.

Second guess, based on the first one:

> abbreviation

Comment: Wow, I keep getting brilliant answers! Unfortunately, this isn't the right answer!

Comment: Well, it was worth trying.. :P  Btw. when I read your riddle, in my head it is vocalized by the voice of Yoda from Star Wars.

Comment: Master Obi Wan, that was intended, though not helpful for the solution eheh!

Answer (score 3):

It seems like a bit of a trick given the title, but...

> OPPORTUNITY?

*I could be there, yet I'll stay hidden.*

> It's often hard to find an opportunity; metaphorically, it's well hidden away.

*Hidden I'll stay, but you'll need me.*

> You often need to wait for an opportunity to do something.

*Need me you will, so I may appear.*

> If you're lucky, an opportunity appears!

*Appear I may, I don't decide.

 Decide I don't, my master does.*

> An opportunity doesn't decide anything by itself; *you* have to decide to take it.

*I'm a word, I tell you words.*

> "Opportunity" is a word.

*I've a task, you know my task.*

> It may be an opportunity to perform some task.

*I'm short, I shorten your path.*

> If you seize an opportunity, it may significantly reduce your labour.

*I've the answer, now tell me it!*

> See above :-)

Comment: Nice, but not the answer!

Answer (score 3):

This might be the deepest, most thought-provoking answer to a riddle ever.  It's

> Siri

I could be there, yet I'll stay hidden.
Hidden I'll stay, but you'll need me.
Need me you will, so I may appear.
Appear I may, I don't decide.
Decide I don't, my master does.

> It's a feature of the phone that stays in the background until the owner asks for it ("Siri, how do I ...")

I'm a word, I tell you words.

> Siri responds to questions in speech.  And, she can define words for you.

I've a task, you know my task

> Siri keeps tasks (reminders, alarms, etc) for you

I'm short, I shorten your path.

> Siri is a short word.  She shortens your path by giving you GPS directions.

I've the answer, now tell me it!

> Siri has all the answers.

Disclaimer

> I don't own an iPhone.

Comment: Cool, but it isn't the correct answer!

Comment: The *Disclaimer* made my day! :D

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps your unreliable friend is ...

> Muse

And why?

> The muse is not visible, yet we need it to create anything worthwhile. It may not appear; the master of the muse is fate. Muses inspire in words and deeds; "I shorten the path" is the least convincing fit for this answer.

Comment: Good thoughs, but this isn't the answer!

Answer (score 2):

I think its a

> Navigation app

**Explanation line by line:**

I could be there, yet I'll stay hidden.
Hidden I'll stay, but you'll need me.
Need me you will, so I may appear.

> You only use your navigation app when you need it.

Appear I may, I don't decide.
Decide I don't, my master does.

> It isn't up to the phone to open the app but the user can.

I'm a word, I tell you words.

> The navigation app tells which path you have to take.

I've a task, you know my task.

> You set it to go to a certain direction

I'm short, I shorten your path.

> It shortens the path by choosing the shortest route.

Comment: Good answer, but not what I'm looking for.

Answer (score 2):

**My Answer**

> tongue

**Reasoning**

I could be there, yet I'll stay hidden.

> very hard to see your own tongue without a mirror

Hidden I'll stay, but you'll need me.

> you need it for tasting

Need me you will, so I may appear.

> when eating

Appear I may, I don't decide.

> tongue can't control itself

Decide I don't, my master does.

> humans do

I'm a word, I tell you words.

> helps you to articulate

I've a task, you know my task.

> we all know the purposes of a tongue

I'm short, I shorten your path.

> chewing is the first step in the digestive process and tongue aids in that

I've the answer, now tell me it!

> you're a tongue!

Comment: I like your answer, but it's not what I'm looking for!

Answer (score 2):

Is it

> History?

I could be there, yet I'll stay hidden.

> History records many event, but some remain hidden

Hidden I'll stay, but you'll need me.

> While not all are recorded, a story of the past is still needed.

Need me you will, so I may appear.

> History exists because you 'will' (in future) need it

Appear I may, I don't decide.

> It's not the one who wrote history decides its content,

Decide I don't, my master does.

> But the people / things in the past.

I'm a word, I tell you words.

> History is a word, and it tells you 'his-story' in words

I've a task, you know my task.

> A task to record the past

I'm short, I shorten your path.

> Human history is short, yet contains valuable information to shorten your path (to success, for the opportunist friend)

I've the answer, now tell me it!

> History!

Comment: I like the attempt, but it's not the answer!